# Javascript callback not working, running callback before ajax request has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand callback. I have this code, which can be run from the console. I want to get the github profiles from the array users, and when they all loaded(displayed on console) I want to display 'Finished' on console. I am using a callback, and I think this is where my issue is.

Unfortunately, 'Finished' is shown on console, and then the data from github. Obviously it is async, and the call back is not working. What can I do?

This is the output

```
VM134355:24 Finished
undefined
VM134355:4 Object {login: "Amichai", id: 313874, avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/313874?v=3", gravatar_id: "", url: "https://api.github.com/users/Amichai"…}
VM134355:5 Amichai has 65 public repositories!
VM134355:4 Object {login: "adamwiggins", id: 177, avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/177?v=3", gravatar_id: "", url: "https://api.github.com/users/adamwiggins"…}
VM134355:5 Adam Wiggins has 94 public repositories!
VM134355:4 Object {login: "fzzr-", id: 888526, avatar_url: "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/888526?v=3", gravatar_id: "", url: "https://api.github.com/users/fzzr-"…}
VM134355:5 Alexander "FIZZΞR" Koz. has 129 public repositories!
```

The code is

```
function makeRequest(url,index,array){
  function printRepoCount() {
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(responseObj);
    console.log(responseObj.name + " has " + responseObj.public_repos + " public repositories!");
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = printRepoCount;
  request.open('get', url, true);
  request.send();
}

function loadPages(files, _callback) {
  files.forEach(makeRequest);
  _callback();
}

var users = ['https://api.github.com/users/Amichai',
'https://api.github.com/users/adamwiggins',
'https://api.github.com/users/fzzr-'];

(function runFunction(){
  loadPages(users, function() {
      console.log('Finished');
    });
})();
```

Comment: You need to use the XHR `onreadystatechange` function to execute the callback after the AJAX request has completed. You're calling the callback immediately after you send the requests, not when they're completed.

Comment: If you want to send multiple AJAX requests and wait for them all to finish, you should look into using promises. And why do you have the jquery tag if you're not using jQuery? Are you willing to use jQuery? It will make this easier.

Comment: Check out the Fetch API as an alternative to XHR. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but if you'd prefer to stick to your code, you can wrap your makeRequest() method with a counter, like so:

```
function makeRequest(url,index,array){
  function printRepoCount() {
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(responseObj);
    console.log(responseObj.name + " has " + responseObj.public_repos + " public repositories!");
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = printRepoCount;
  request.open('get', url, true);
  request.send();

  // Don't forget to return the request!
  return request;
}

function loadPages(files, _callback) {
  var files_count = files.length,
      files_loaded = 0;

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    var request = makeRequest(file);
    var req_onload = request.onload;
    request.onload = function(t) {
      req_onload.bind(this)(t);
      files_loaded++;
      if (files_loaded === files_count) {
        _callback();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I changed `loadPages` to change the `onload` method of the request object returned from `makeRequest` - first I save the original onload in `req_onload` and then I replace it with a method that fires the original (in the context of the event itself) and then increments a counter (`files_loaded`). When `files_loaded` reaches `files_count`, it fires your `_callback` method.

You can check it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yoavmatchulsky/oLua9m3q/)

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for, I saw the counter in other examples but wanted to stay away. I was trying promises but was going nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and its `Deferred` object to get promises from each of the AJAX requests. Then wait for all of them to finish with `$.when()` and call the callback.

```
function loadPages(files, _callback) {
    var promises = $.map(files, function(file) {
        return $.getJSON(file, function(responseObj) {
            console.log(responseObj);
            console.log(responseObj.name + " has " + responseObj.public_repos + " public repositories!");
        })
    });
    $.when.apply(null, promises).then(_callback);
}
```

If you don't want to use jQuery (but then why did you put it in your tags?), the structure using the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API will be similar, because it also returns a promise. You would use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to complete.

Comment: Yeah, I should have put ajax rather then jquery. I wanted to be able to do this in pure javascript. But your solution is good. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically javascript follows single threaded synchronous execution.

So basically it reads the code line by line and executes it. The AJAX request is taken into account by javascript synchronously only but the response of it is not in the hands of javascript. It may take time depending on a lot of factors(internet speed, API etc.)

So basically you need to execute the callback function once you have the response from the API

Although using promises is very much recommended in this case, but still you can see the solution to understand callback

You can do something like this:

```
 var users = ['https://api.github.com/users/Amichai',
'https://api.github.com/users/adamwiggins',
'https://api.github.com/users/fzzr-'];

function makeRequest(url, _callback){
  var counter = 0
  function printRepoCount() {
    counter++;
    var responseObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    console.log(responseObj);
    console.log(responseObj.name + " has " + responseObj.public_repos + " public repositories!");
    if(counter == users.length){
        _callback(); // execute the callback after the response from the ajax  
    }
   request is displayed.
  }
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onload = printRepoCount;
  request.open('get', url, true);
  request.send();
}

function loadPages(files, _callback) {
  files.forEach(makeRequest, _callback);
}

(function runFunction(){
  loadPages(users, function() {
      console.log('Finished');
    });
})();
```

Comment: This will call _callback on every request. he wants it to be called once everything is finished

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky Thanks for pointing out the error. Will the edit help? I know using promised would have been more efficient here. But I just wanted to explain callback as per OP question